# List each custom post type separately in a wp_query without repeating the loop

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using an AJAX search to pull 3 custom post types from wordpress (post, guides, advice). As you can see in my `if while` loop, the results show which results are which but I'm trying to section them out individually so it will show something like this:

**section 1**

blog posts

**section 2**

guides

The problem seems to be that I need to edit the if while loop because adding anything inside that loop will just cause it to be in that loop. Does anyone know the best way to modify the if while loop to achieve this?

```
function data_fetch(){
$the_query = new WP_Query( 
  array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 6, 
    's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 
    'post_type' => array('post' , 'guides', 'advice'),
    'post_status' => 'publish'
  ) 
);


global $post;

if( $the_query->have_posts()) :
    while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $type = get_post_type();
    $term =  $_POST['keyword'];
    $i++;
    $total = $the_query->found_posts;
    ?>
        <span class="search-title">
            <?php if ($type == 'post'):?>
                <?php echo 'Article: ';?>
                <?php elseif($type == 'guide' ):?>
                <?php echo 'Guide: ';?>
                <?php elseif($type == 'advice' ):?>
                <?php echo 'advice: ';?>
            <?php endif;?>

            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a><br>
        </span>


    <?php endwhile; ?>


    <?php 
  wp_reset_postdata();  
 else: 
  echo '<h3>No Results Found</h3>';
endif;
die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd probably just do three separate queries. They seem simple enough that it shouldn't cause any issues at all. Otherwise you have to either sort through or reorder the `WP_Query` results *somehow*.

If you're set on the single query, however - since these are such short HTML strings, I'd probably just control the output with the [`Output Buffer`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

Basically you can create an associative array, and add the HTML strings to the appropriate keys. You could get a bit more elaborate and have them be nested arrays, but since your output is so light, you can probably get by just by having HTML strings as the values for the keys.

I took the liberty of cleaning up your code a little bit and removing some unused variables, etc.

```
function data_fetch(){
    // Build the Query Arguments
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
        's'              => esc_attr($_POST['keyword']),
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'post_type'      => array('post' , 'guides', 'advice'),
        'post_status'    => 'publish'
    ) );

    // Do we have posts?
    if( $the_query->have_posts()){
        // We do. Start an array that will fill with HTML from the output buffer
        $output = array(
            'post' => '',
            'guides' => '',
            'advice' => '',
        );

        // Loop through the posts
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ){
            $the_query->the_post();
            ob_start(); // Turn on the output buffer
            $type = get_post_type(); ?>

            <span class="search-title">
                <?php echo ($type == 'post') ? 'Article: ' : ucwords($type).': '; // Output "Articles: " for posts, or just capitalize the other post type names ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a><br>
            </span>
            <?php $output[$type] .= ob_get_clean(); // Add the HTML output from the buffer to our array
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();

        // Here we have an array with 3 HTML strings that we can output wherever
        echo $output['post'];
        echo $output['guides'];
        echo $output['advice'];
    } else {
        echo '<h3>No Results Found</h3>';
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the best answer thanks but it's only pulling one entry from each output. How do I pull them all or at least increase the number of results for each one?

Comment: actually the echo $output['xxxx'] do not work it just spits out 0, any further tips? thanks!

Comment: Apologies, I meant to use the concatenation operator! Change `$output[$type] = ob_get_clean();` to `$output[$type] .= ob_get_clean();` (note the period before the equals sign). If you're not getting anything in the output now, it's probably because your query isn't getting any of that post type. For instance, if you have one of each, and then post 6 new `guides`, you'll only receive `guides` and no `post` or `advice` items, because the 6 most recent items being fetched by the query are only `guides`.

Comment: Ah I see it works now thanks! Is there a way to limit how much each output is? Like you said, if I post 6 new guides it will only show up guides. Just curious if there's a way to limit say like 3 total across the board.

Comment: Yes - If you need to guarantee a certain maximum of each, you'd need to go back to what I mentioned originally and do 3 separate queries - one for each of the post types

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your concern, I propose to divide your code by creating a generic class.
and you make calls to the different Post Type :

```
class Custom_Query {

public $post_type;
public $key_word;

public function __construct($post_type, $keyword) {
    $this->post_type = $post_type;
    $this->key_word = $keyword;
}

public function getResult() {
    echo '<h1>Article : ' . $this->post_type . '</h1>';
    $the_query = new WP_Query(
            array(
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        's' => esc_attr($this->key_word),
        'post_type' => array($this->post_type),
        'post_status' => 'publish'
            )
    );
    if ($the_query->have_posts()):
        while ($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post();

            echo '<span class="search-title">';
            echo '<a href=" ' . esc_url(post_permalink()) . '">' . the_title() . '</a><br>';
            echo '</span>';

        endwhile;
    else:
        echo '<h3>No Results Found</h3>';

    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

}
global $post;
$type = get_post_type();
$term = $_POST['keyword'];
$article = new Custom_Query($type, $term);
$article->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track initially.  You can just use the standard post objects to check for post type.  You can adjust to fit your needs, but try something like this:

```
<?php

query = new WP_Query( array( 
        's'              => esc_attr($_POST['keyword']),
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'post_type'      => array('post' , 'guides', 'advice'),
        'post_status'    => 'publish'
    ) );

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
       while ($query->have_posts()):
          $query->the_post(); 
?>


    <div class="posts">

<?php
        if ($query->post->post_type === 'post') {
            // add your content
        } else if ($query->post->post_type === 'guides' {
            // add your content
        } else {
            // add your content

        }

?>
    </div>

<?php endwhile;

    } else {

    // no posts found

     }
```